# inverse of image matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix, inverse

I am using two images. I read and stroded into matrix in opencv using C++. Now, I want to inverse of one image matrix. 
I used `invM1 = M1.inv(CV_LU);(where invM1 and M1 both are matrix)`. I got

> Opencv error:Assertation failed.

Can you help me solve how this error occurred, what the error means, and potential solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your matrix square? Otherwise you need to go with the pseudo-inverse. See the documentation of `inv()`:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-inv